# Copying a chart from Excel to PowerPoint and keeping the Source Formatting using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am looping though worksheets of an excel workbook and trying to plot some charts and then past those charts in a PowerPoint presentation.

My pseudocode looks like this

```
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 2

for each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   Dim myChart2 As Chart
   Set myChart2 = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
   'DO chart stuff

   Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(counter, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
      With ppSlide.Shapes
        If Not .HasTitle Then
            .AddTitle.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Title"
        End If
        ppSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ws.Name

         myChart2.ChartArea.Copy

         ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting")

      End With
    counter = counter + 1
    ws.ChartObjects.Delete


Next ws
```

Unfortunately all the charts are dumped on the first slide instead of each chart on every slide. Could anyone help me rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

for each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   Dim myChart2 As Chart
   Set myChart2 = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
   'DO chart stuff

   Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(counter, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
      With ppSlide.Shapes
        If Not .HasTitle Then
            .AddTitle.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Title"
        End If
        ppSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ws.Name

        'Add slide to presentation
        PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add _
            PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly
        PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide _
            PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        Set PPSlide = PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides( _
            PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)

       ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting")
       ...
```

Comment: Sorry! I do have counter. I did define it outside   the loop.

Comment: Oh I see. I updated the code. You'll need to add a slide in each loop